# Create a shortcode to display custom post types with a specific taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, shortcode

I created a page template to list all products of a specific product line.
Now I want to list all posts from this custom post type (products) based on the taxonomy described in the shortcode for each page.

Example:

Page "List of all Prime products"

[products line="prime"]

I tried this code:

```
function shortcode_mostra_produtos ( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'default' => ''
  ), $atts );
    $terms = get_terms('linhas');
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'produtos',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'linhas',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $atts,
        ),
      ),
     );
     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo ' "'.get_the_title().'" ';
        endwhile;
     }
}
add_shortcode( 'produtos','shortcode_mostra_produtos' );
```

Comment: Have you attempted to do this or have any code to show?

Comment: I tried this: https://gist.github.com/luanpiegas/51560598cbee58e6881531ee003feab0

Comment: That's a good start - people here are somtimes more inclined to answer questions when they know that the asker has attempted a solution ( and are not just asking for code ). It may be beneficial to edit your question and add that code snippet :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, it's always good to register shortcode during `init` versus just in your general `functions.php` file. At the very least `add_shortcode()` should be in `init`. Anyway, let's begin!

Whenever you use [`add_shortcode()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) the first parameter is going to be the name of the shortcode and the 2nd will be the callback function. This means that:

```
[products line="prime"]
```

Should be instead:

```
[produtos line="prime"]
```

So far we have this:

```
/**
 * Register all shortcodes
 *
 * @return null
 */
function register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'produtos', 'shortcode_mostra_produtos' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes' );

/**
 * Produtos Shortcode Callback
 * - [produtos]
 * 
 * @param Array $atts
 *
 * @return string
 */
function shortcode_mostra_produtos( $atts ) {
    /** Our outline will go here
}
```

Let's take a look at processing attributes. The way [`shortcode_atts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) works is that it will try to match attributes passed to the shortcode with attributes in the passed array, left side being the key and the right side being the defaults. So we need to change `defaults` to `line` instead - if we want to default to a category, this would be the place:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'line' => ''
), $atts );
```

IF the user adds a attribute to the shortcode `line="test"` then our array index `line` will hold `test`:

```
echo $atts['line']; // Prints 'test'
```

All other attributes will be ignored unless we add them to the `shortcode_atts()` array. Finally it's just the WP_Query and printing what you need:

```
/**
 * Register all shortcodes
 *
 * @return null
 */
function register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'produtos', 'shortcode_mostra_produtos' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes' );

/**
 * Produtos Shortcode Callback
 * 
 * @param Array $atts
 *
 * @return string
 */
function shortcode_mostra_produtos( $atts ) {
    global $wp_query,
        $post;

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'line' => ''
    ), $atts );

    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 200,
        'post_type'         => 'produtos',
        'orderby'           => 'menu_order title',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'tax_query'         => array( array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'linhas',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array( sanitize_title( $atts['line'] ) )
        ) )
    ) );

    if( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
        return false;
    }

    while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        echo the_title();
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    add_shortcode( 'product-list','bpo_product_list' );
function bpo_product_list ( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'category' => ''
  ), $atts );
    $terms = get_terms('product_category');
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'product',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $atts,
        ),
      ),
     );
     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo ' "'.get_the_title().'" ';
        endwhile;
     }

     else {
            echo  'Sorry, no posts were found';
          }
}
```

In above code, I have created product CPT and product_category taxonomy for product CPT.

[product-list category="shirts"]

The above code is perfectly works!

Answer (score -1):

**Try this **

```
function shortcode_bws_quiz_maker($id)
{
  if($id!='')
  {
    $post_id=$id[0];
    $html='';
    global $wpdb;
   $args=array('post_type'=>'post_type','p'=>$post_id);
   $wp_posts=new WP_Query($args);
   $posts=$wp_posts->posts;
  $html.="What you to get write here";
    return $html;

  }
  else
  {
    return 'Please enter correct shortcode';    
  }

}
add_shortcode('bws_quiz_maker','shortcode_bws_quiz_maker');
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: This answer does not answer the OP at all - it seems completely unrelated. It also lacks any explanation of what it is supposed to do or how to use it.